# C header file dependencies

Tags: c, include, header-files

I would always typically include dependencies in my header files so that when adding that header to a source file, I don't need to dig around for the other required headers to make it compile.

However, after reviewing some other coding standards, it appears that this is often banned, with the requirement that a header file will not contain any #include statements.

I can't really find any discussion on this - so what would be the reason for banning such a practice, or is it purely down to preference?

--

E.g.
typedef.h contains a typedef for U8.
my_header.h declares void display_message(U8 arg);

Should the reference to typedef.h go into my_source_file.c or into my_header.h ??

Comment: Where is a coding standard that says this?

Comment: One example would be the [Netrino coding standard](http://www.barrgroup.com/Coding-Standard-Muse), but I have seen others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no good reason for not allowing headers to include their prerequisites.

Consider deleting an `#include` from a source file. For example, suppose the code has been modified to no longer use `foo.h`, so the `#include` for that is being deleted. But the source files has a dozen `#include` statements. Which other ones should you delete because they are no longer needed? Hopefully, `foo.h` documents its prerequisites, so you can identify those candidates for deletion. However, if you delete their `#include` statements, you might be deleting a prerequisite that is needed by a different header file. So you must check the prerequisites of **every** header file.

In contrast, if headers include their prerequisites, then you can simply delete `#include <foo.h>` and be done with it.

Comment: Yeah, this one exactly.

Comment: Yes, these were my thoughts too.. glad to head it's not just me so I will probably continue as I am! :)

Answer (score -2):

Includes should go in the source file. The header should only declare functions and variables of your source code file (that is typically the standard).

Comment: Why? "You should do X" is not an answer to the question "Why should I do X?"